# How to parse XSD file using c#

Tags: c#, xsd

I want to read XSD File. But unable to find a proper way to parse XSD file.

```
<xsd:group name="group_name">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Some text is here</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Element_1" type="string">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Some text is here</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Element_2" type="string">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Some text is here</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:group>
```

I want to read each group in my file, a sequence in that group and element in that sequence. And also need to read annotation of each group, I can element.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSD File are XML file, so you can read ot using XML parser such as LINQ which is a query to read data from data source, the link bellow is a good source about it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx 
So, the first step is to load the xml file then read it by LINQ query

Comment: Or he can generate a class corresponding to the [XML schema](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd) and deserialize it