# How to parse a Generic XML File in C# to create a Table in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have this Generic XML file, I want to parse it so I can create a SQL server table according to the XML data :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Student">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**I want to recover the following data:**

```
Student, 

Id / integer

Name / String

City / String
```

Student will be the name of the table, and Id, Name and City are the columns. All I need is how to parse the XML file and recover the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read and parse an XML file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c).  If you are having a specific problem, edit your question to focus on that.  Otherwise it looks like you are just asking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: See also [How to parse XSD file using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855024/how-to-parse-xsd-file-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Does [How to parse an XSD to get the information from <xsd:simpleType> elements using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11569264/3744182) sufficiently answer your question?

Comment: I don't agree this is a proper duplicate of [How do I read and parse an XML file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/642293/3744182).  That question addresses ways to parse any XML file, but OP's file is specifically an XSD file (in XML format).  As such there are higher-level tools available to deserialize and interpret such a file.  [How to parse XSD file using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34855024/3744182) would seem to be a duplicate but unfortunately it's only answer is a link-only answer referring to MSDN documentation for, once again, generic XML parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML file is an *[XML Schema Definition (XSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C))* file that *formally describe[s] the elements in an Extensible Markup Language (XML) document.*  You can load such a file into an [`XmlSchemaSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xmlschemaset-for-schema-compilation) schema collection, compile it, and then interrogate the schemas thereby defined to get your main element name and its properties.

Let's say that you have a string `xsdString` that contains the XSD shown in your question.  Then you can load it, compile it, and print out the complex elements and their properties as follows:

```
// Load the xsdString into an XmlSchemaSet.
// If loading from a file use a StreamReader rather than a StringReader
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
using (var reader = new StringReader(xsdString))
{
    schemaSet.Add(XmlSchema.Read(reader, null));
}

// Compile the schema
schemaSet.Compile();

// Iterate over the schemas
// Code adapted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/traversing-xml-schemas
foreach (XmlSchema schema in schemaSet.Schemas())
{
    // Iterate over the complex types in the schema
    foreach (XmlSchemaElement element in schema.Elements.Values)
    {
        var complexType = element.ElementSchemaType as XmlSchemaComplexType;
        if (complexType == null)
            continue;

        Console.WriteLine("Complex element: {0}", element.Name);

        // If the complex type has any attributes, get an enumerator
        // and write each attribute name to the console.
        if (complexType.AttributeUses.Count > 0)
        {
            var enumerator = complexType.AttributeUses.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var attribute = (XmlSchemaAttribute)enumerator.Value;
                var name = attribute.Name;
                var type = attribute.AttributeSchemaType.TypeCode;

                Console.WriteLine("   Attribute {0}: {1}", name, type);
            }
        }

        // Get the sequence particle of the complex type.
        var sequence = complexType.ContentTypeParticle as XmlSchemaSequence;
        if (sequence != null)
        {
            // Iterate over each XmlSchemaElement in the Items collection.
            foreach (XmlSchemaElement childElement in sequence.Items)
            {
                var name = childElement.Name;
                var type = childElement.ElementSchemaType.TypeCode;

                Console.WriteLine("   Element {0}: {1}", name, type);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs

> ```
> Complex element: Student
>    Element Id: Integer
>    Element Name: String
>    Element City: String
> ```

Note that the XSD type `xs:integer` corresponds to an *unbounded* integer, not necessarily one that will fit in an `Int32` or `Int64`.

References:

- [Traversing XML Schemas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/traversing-xml-schemas)
- [How to parse an XSD to get the information from <xsd:simpleType> elements using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11569264/3744182)
- [XSD: What is the difference between xs:integer and xs:int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15336872/3744182)

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sO5Q8d).

Comment: I don't know how to say thank you ! you really deserve thos 11 Golds